# Command VSCode runs to compile C++ code does not reference include path, resulting in 'no such file or directory' despite being fine when linting

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-code, include-path

I'm trying to use the Boost library on Windows 10 using Visual Studio Code with C++17. I know the code is valid since it was copied from the documentation. I downloaded & unzipped the latest version of Boost and I created a `.vscode` folder and `c_cpp_settings.json` inside it and have added the path (C:/Users/.../boost) to both `"configurations">"includePath"` and `"configuration">"browse">"path"` as well as settings.json: `"c_Cpp.default.includePath"` in order to allow my program to include `.hpp` files from Boost.

Supposedly I'm supposed to *also* add this to `tasks.json` but I don't know how to find it and in terms of creating it myself, I wouldn't know what to write there. Supposedly Ctrl+Shift+B then selecting cl.exe creates the file for you according to the documentation, but this does not do anything for me.

VSCode's linting is fine with the code and has no problems with the include path when it is in the state that it is in the first paragraph, but when I run it and it shows the command run, **the path to Boost does not appear anywhere** in it.

The command run is `cd (absolute path to folder I currently have open) && g++ BoostTest.cpp -o BoostTest && (absolute path to folder I currently have open)\BoostTest`.
**You can see here that there is no mention of Boost at all.**
One thing to note though, is that `"configurations">"browse">"path"` in `c_cpp_properties.json` is `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/VS/include/*"` and `"configurations">"compilerPath"` is `""C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe""`. I don't use Visual Studio (because of severe performance issues) and I was not aware until now that VSCode relied on Visual Studio. The command used by VSCode is `g++` not `cl` so this may have something to do with it.

Note: Using g++.exe, cl.exe and cpp.exe all result in the same error.

The exact code (which is not mine) is

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

and when connecting the include path to the path on the first line, it does in fact lead to an existing file.

Additionally, I tried with an older version of Boost, 1.53.0, but I had exactly the same issue, but I haven't tried to use any other C++ libraries.

This is my first time trying to use the include path at all, so I may be missing something obvious and fundamental.
I'm happy to provide more clarification and information if required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: VSCode is independent of Visual Studio (does not need VS to be installed to work) and can be used with virtually any toolchain you want. First, can you build this example by hand from the command line (or a makefile or CMake or whatever)? You'll need to do that in order to expect that you can configure VSCode to do the same. You should see an include flag in there somewhere that points to your boost installation. Second, do you really need Boost.Lambda? It is -- though a brilliant piece of work in its day -- very much obsolete with C++11's language support for lambdas.

Comment: You could try to use absolute path, like `#include <C:\Program Files\PCL 1.8.1\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost-1_64\boost\shared_ptr.hpp>`.